# Really thin footer

Tags: header-footer, margins

I am using the below LaTeX template to create small posters with coloured background and with a wide variety of dimensions, usually very far from the ordinary paper formats. This of course sometimes causes problems because LaTeX is, generally, very A4-oriented, at least from my layman's perspective.

The problem I am currently dealing with is to have my name and e-mail address displayed at the center of the bottom margin, as a kind of very small footer. However, my experiments with `fancyhdr` were rather unsuccessful, since I had to increase the size of the bottom margin quite a lot in order for the footer to become visible. I would rather want to avoid chaing the layout that much because of such a small detail, so does anybody have a good solution to this?

P.S. As might be obvious from the below template, I am no skilled LaTeX user, so feel free to point out whatever else I might be doing completely wrong. ;-)

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\color{black}


% If I want a picture background:
%\newlength\imageheight
%\newlength\imagewidth
%\newcommand*\imagefilename{../TEMPLATES/Backgrounds/Yellow(1).png}
%
%\newcommand{\imagescale}{0.6}
%\settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics[scale=\imagescale]{\imagefilename}}
%\settowidth{\imagewidth}{\includegraphics[scale=\imagescale]{\imagefilename}}
%
%\usepackage[
%       paperwidth=\imagewidth,
%       paperheight = \imageheight,
%       top=0.03\imagewidth,
%       bottom=0.03\imagewidth,
%       left=0.03\imagewidth,
%       right=0.03\imagewidth
%   ]{geometry}
%   
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
%\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{\imagefilename}

%If I want a homogeneous colour background: 
\newlength\mypagewidth
\newlength\mypageheight
\setlength\mypagewidth{200pt}
\setlength\mypageheight{115pt}
\usepackage[
        paperwidth=\mypagewidth,
        paperheight = \mypageheight,
        top=0.03\mypageheight,
        bottom=0.03\mypageheight,
        left=0.03\mypagewidth,
        right=0.03\mypagewidth
    ]{geometry}
\pagecolor{black}

%Other packages
\usepackage{enumerate,siunitx,comment,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,array,xspace,xkeyval,xfrac,bm,mathtools,listings, wasysym, tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{cmbright} %Sans-serif in math mode.

%Language:
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%A \yesnumber command, allowing me to easily insert equation numers.
\newcommand*{\yesnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

%Special commands:
\renewcommand{\le}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}
\newcommand{\N}[0]{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}[0]{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}[0]{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}[0]{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}[0]{\mathbb{C}}


\pagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{mathdots}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        {\Huge Title}
    \end{center}

    Lorem ipsum.........................
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. The package allows you to easily place arbitrary material at the desired position in all or some of the pages of your document; you can control the attributes of the material (color,scale,position,angle,etc.). A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

%\color{black}


% If I want a picture background:
%\newlength\imageheight
%\newlength\imagewidth
%\newcommand*\imagefilename{../TEMPLATES/Backgrounds/Yellow(1).png}
%
%\newcommand{\imagescale}{0.6}
%\settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics[scale=\imagescale]{\imagefilename}}
%\settowidth{\imagewidth}{\includegraphics[scale=\imagescale]{\imagefilename}}
%
%\usepackage[
%       paperwidth=\imagewidth,
%       paperheight = \imageheight,
%       top=0.03\imagewidth,
%       bottom=0.03\imagewidth,
%       left=0.03\imagewidth,
%       right=0.03\imagewidth
%   ]{geometry}
%   
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
%\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{\imagefilename}

%If I want a homogeneous colour background: 
\newlength\mypagewidth
\newlength\mypageheight
\setlength\mypagewidth{200pt}
\setlength\mypageheight{115pt}
\usepackage[
        paperwidth=\mypagewidth,
        paperheight = \mypageheight,
        top=0.03\mypageheight,
        bottom=0.03\mypageheight,
        left=0.03\mypagewidth,
        right=0.03\mypagewidth
    ]{geometry}
%\pagecolor{black}

%Other packages
\usepackage{enumerate,siunitx,comment,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,array,xspace,xkeyval,xfrac,bm,mathtools,listings, wasysym, tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{cmbright} %Sans-serif in math mode.

%Language:
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%A \yesnumber command, allowing me to easily insert equation numers.
\newcommand*{\yesnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

%Special commands:
\renewcommand{\le}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}
\newcommand{\N}[0]{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}[0]{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}[0]{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}[0]{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}[0]{\mathbb{C}}


\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=0.6,
  angle=0,
  color=black,
  position=current page.south,
  contents={Some text},
  vshift=6pt
}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Huge Title}
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum.........................
\end{document}
```

[image]

The global option `20pt` is not recognized by the `article` class.

Comment: It's working PERFECTLY, thanks. :-)